# Importing a python module into colab - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, modulenotfounderror

Im trying to import a colab file as a module with a function (def) to be used in this new colab file.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

I tried all of these calls:

```
#!cp "drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Aulas_Cursos/test_module" .
!cp '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Aulas_Cursos/test_module' .

#import sys
#sys.path.insert(0,'/content/drive/My Drive/ColabNotebooks/Aulas_Cursos')
#sys.path.append('/content/gdrive/My Drive')

import test_module
```

But i got the same error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-1a0689a1a9af> in <module>()
----> 1 import test_module

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_module'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: have you tried with `sys.path.append('/content/gdrive/My Drive//Colab Notebooks/Aulas_Cursos/')` ?